# rosdep update error (gentoo.yaml empty)

Tags: ros, rosdep, update, github, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just noticed a strange error when executing `rosdep update`.

```
$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit file:///etc/ros/rosdep/local.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml]:
    rosdep data from [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml] is not a YAML dictionary
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "groovy"
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "hydro"
Query rosdistro index https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "indigo"
Add distro "hydro"
updated cache in /Users/demmeln/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
ERROR: Not all sources were able to be updated.
[[[
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml]:
    rosdep data from [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml] is not a YAML dictionary
]]]
```

If I look at https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml, it looks fine, however for me, the raw version https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml which rosdep downloads seems to be empty (0 bytes). Is this some faulty caching on github's side, or somewhere on my machine? I get the same with browser and from command line (wget), so not sure what kind of cache that would be...

Can anyone confirm the empty file with the "raw" link?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146921/rosdep-update-error-(gentoo.yaml-empty)/) by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an opened a support email with github and they are looking into it, but I too think it is related to the roll out of their new CDN. It is safe to ignore this error for now, the file it is failing to retrieve is empty and vestigial anyways.

In fact you can get rid of it by re-initilaizing rosdep:

- Run `rosdep init`, it will fail because it's already initialized
- Follow the instructions it gives you to remove the config files
- Run `rosdep init` again
- Run `rosdep update` (hoepfully without error)

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-02**:
Also, it looks to be resolved now, the Github support team emailed me letting me know it was resolved.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
Yeah, it seemed to have started working yesterday. Thanks for the hint with removing the gentoo entry since it has been removed anyways.